# How to gather hierarchical data items and build a tree considering their dependencies

Tags: sql, firebird

There is a table containing hierarchical data, e.g.:

```
| table "attribute_instances"                           |
+----+----------+------------+---------------+----------+
| id | tree_ref | parent_ref | attribute_ref | data_ref |
+----+----------+------------+---------------+----------+
|  1 |        1 |         -1 |             1 |        1 |
|  2 |        1 |          1 |             2 |        2 |
|  3 |        2 |         -1 |             1 |        3 |
|  4 |        2 |          3 |             2 |        2 |
```

It contains many separate trees (see `tree_ref`), each of them instantiating some attributes (see `attribute_ref`) and have a data reference `data_reference`, where data might be referenced in other trees, too.

Now, those trees should be merged into a single tree, in which (by now) up to 5 attributes may be chosen as level for that tree, e.g.:

```
attribute => level
------------------
        2 =>     1
        1 =>     2
```

What I need is one or more queries, that collects the data from table `attribute_instances` and gives a result as follows:

```
| table "merged_attribute_instances"         |
+----+------------+---------------+----------+
| id | parent_ref | attribute_ref | data_ref |
|  5 |         -1 |             2 |        2 |
|  6 |          5 |             1 |        1 |
|  7 |          5 |             1 |        3 |
```

This is the desired merged tree:

```
id:5 - data_ref:2
  id:6 - data_ref:1
  id:7 - data_ref:3
```

Note, that `attribute_ref = 2` occurs only once in the resulting tree, as all instances of it have same `data_ref` value (that is `2`).

I've tried some joins like

```
select *
  from attribute_instances a
  join attribute_instances b on a.tree_ref = b.tree_ref
```

But that seems to me being bad for having user-defined tree depth. I'm sure there is a better solution.

UPDATE: I should add, that table `merged_attribute_instances` is a temporary table. And the collecting query is iterated with `for..do`. In the loop the collected `attribute_instances` are then added to the temporary table.

Comment: I'd guess you could get it done with recursive common table expressions, but my head always starts hurting when I start thinking of recursive CTEs ;)

Comment: I fail to see how you want to go from the data in `attribute_instances` to `merge_attribute_instances`.

Comment: Does the tree hiearchy defined in `attribute_instances` have anything to do with the resulting tree, or is it purely the values of attribute_ref?

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel It is purely the values of `attribute_ref` and `data_ref`. But they must occur in the same tree to be merged in the result.

Comment: But in your example code they are not in the same tree and yet get merged.

Comment: Sorry, you misunderstood my last comment, as it was likely misunderstandable in review. It meant that subtrees have to be build in condition that all of its items must occur in the same original tree.

Answer (score 0):

OK, then use this:

```
SET TERM ^ ;

create or alter procedure GETTREENODES
returns (
    ID integer,
    TREE_REF integer,
    PARENT_REF integer,
    ATTRIBUTE_REF integer,
    DATA_REF integer)
as
declare variable DATAREFEXISTS varchar(4096);
begin
 DATAREFEXISTS = ',';
 for
    Select id, tree_ref, parent_ref, attribute_ref, data_ref from attribute_instances
     into :id, :tree_ref, :parent_ref, :attribute_ref, :data_ref
 do begin
    IF (position(',' || data_ref || ',', DATAREFEXISTS) =0) THEN
    begin
      suspend;
      DATAREFEXISTS = DATAREFEXISTS || data_ref || ',' ;
    end
 end
end^

SET TERM ; ^

/* Following GRANT statetements are generated automatically */

GRANT SELECT ON ATTRIBUTE_INSTANCES TO PROCEDURE GETTREENODES;

/* Existing privileges on this procedure */

GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE GETTREENODES TO SYSDBA;
```

Call it like this:

```
Select * from gettreenodes
order by tree_ref, parent_ref
```